# Python trabalhando com texto

Tags: python, txt, text, texto

Bom dia,
Sou novo na programação e estou criando um código básico só de juntar e alterar texto.
Ja consegui criar boa parte. As etapas de criar nova pasta, copiar e colar e juntar os bloco de notas dentro do programa esta funcionando. Adiciono um texto, tambem consigo. O que nao estou conseguindo fazer é alterar o valor depois do H.

Coloquei em negrito a parte que nao funciona. O codigo roda ate o final sem alterar a linha.

```
#n RECEBE O NUMERO DO ARQUIVO
# MODO LEITURA
# ABRIR PARA COPIAR CONTEUDO
with open(nome_arq[n], 'r') as file2:
    # for linha in file:
    linha = file2.read()

    # DESCOBRIR JEITO DE ADICIONAR E RECONECER O  m6
    if 'M6' in linha:
        print('CODIGO INVALIDO\nJA EXISTE M6')
        print('APAGUE E COMECE NOVAMENTE')
        exit()



    print('*' * 50)
    T = int(input('INSIRA O T: '))
    H = int(input('INSIRA O H: '))
    a = linha.rfind('H')
    b = a + 2
    a = a + 1
    a = linha[a]
    b = linha[b]
    R = 'H{}{}'.format(a, b)
    S = 'H{}'.format(H)

    linha = linha.replace('G21', "G21\nT{}\nM6".format(T))
    print('ADICIONADO T E M')
    **linha = linha.replace('G43 H{}', "G43 H{}".format(R, S))**
    print('H{}{}'.format(a, b))
    print('H{}'.format(H))
    print('LETRA')
    print(R, S)
```

Answer (score 0):

Podes usar a variável R no primeiro parâmetro e inserir o S. Depois é preciso gravar a linha no ficheiro.

```
    linha = linha.replace('G43 '+R, "G43 {}".format(S))
    with open("file.txt", 'w') as file2:
        file2.write(linha)
```

Comment: Deu certo, muito obrigado, faz semanas que estou tentando.